# WebRtc not running in iOS browsers.

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, html

Make a webrtc script with nodejs and it working nicely windows and android but it doesn't work in iOS any way to run webRTC in iOS

Comment: which werRTC lib you are using ?

Comment: Not using lib files use nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Till iOS 9 there is no support for WebRTC in Safari But apple has given final approval to include that in upcoming safari browser so its in development stage as of now

In Android webRTC support was added in 5.0 only so it previous versions of android it won't work

[image: webRTC in Webkit]

Here is the [official reference](https://webkit.org/status/)

***Possible solutions:***

You can develop a Mobile app that supports webRTC in iOS and Android.
Fortunately [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc) supports WebRTC.
So you can easily develop mobile apps as its cross platform framework.